# SQLCipher findLibrary returned null

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sqlcipher

I recently updated the sqlcipher so that it is able to work with Android version 4.4 which works well with every device i have tested it on, mainly Android versions 4+. Aside from one Galaxy note 8 where i get the following error:

```
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load stlport_shared from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/uk.co.onefile.assessoroffline-2.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/uk.co.onefile.assessoroffline-2]: findLibrary returned null
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(SQLiteDatabase.java:142)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(SQLiteDatabase.java:137)
```

This is when `SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this);` is called. I was wondering if anyone can help me with this. I have been pulling my hair our over this problem for the past couple of days and have got nowhere with it.

Comment: then compile(or find the binary) SQLCipher c/c++ code with static stlport(seems like your compiled version is using stlport shared library which seems to be not available on your galaxy note)

Comment: Try downloading and installing https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/ConstantsSecure on your Note 8. If that works, see what is different between its `libs/` directory and yours. If it doesn't work, then there may be an issue with the Note 8, and I'll want to investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and could fix it with Dharmik's answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25811928/150015) (that is, in your app/src/main/, create a jniLibs directory where you drop the library folders)